# Android Emulator Not Responding to Clicks

Tags: android, android-emulator

I  tried to uninstall apps in settings screen, but android emulator won't respond to my clicks. The tabs do highlight, but won't load the content. It happens not only for this one, but all emulators with API level 8+. Why is that? Sorry I can't post images here.

Comment: have u tested on device?

Comment: You mean a hardware device? No. The phone I have is at API level 8, but some of the methods I use require API level 9+

Comment: if ur problem is only uninstallation of apk file then i think u should test once one real device ..you can post me apk file may be i can help you

Comment: I could do it through the command line, it's just strange why it happens. Every tab on the settings screen is not responding to the clicks(not just the applications tab), and it happens to all of the devices I've created with API level 8+

Comment: i can suugest u one thing try running ur application in app player